ToolbarMiddleware causes NoReverseMatch for 'cms_usersettings_change' when trying to add Django CMS to existing project
I'm trying to add Django CMS to an existing Django 5.1.4 project, but I'm stuck on this error message when I try to load the CMS start page:
Reverse for 'cms_usersettings_change' not found. 'cms_usersettings_change' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

It seems to trip over {% cms_toolbar %} in site-packages/cms/templates/cms/welcome.html on line 14.
So far, I've followed the instructions for adding Django CMS to an existing project up to and including the URLs configuration. Migrations work fine, cms check finds no issues. I want to set up the CMS behind the URL /cms/, so my urls.py looks like this:
urlpatterns = [
    # ... paths for my own application here ...

    path("cms/", include("cms.urls")),
]

As soon as I disable cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware in settings.py, I can see the CMS start page, but this would disable the toolbar. I've also tried step debugging using my own implementation of a ToolbarMiddleware, and using i18n_patterns, but this did not help. Is there something I'm missing?
